# Do we have a datagrid control or something equivalent to show report in maui

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

There isn't a control for datagrid that views data in rows and columns that I could find from Microsoft instead of from third party. When is Microsoft going to release it?

Answer (score 2):

Right now there is no such control that I am aware of. Not within .NET MAUI itself nor in the .NET MAUI community toolkit nor in a third-party free control.

I know that nothing is on the roadmap right now for .NET MAUI and the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit. Of course I don't know what is being developed by the community.

As you already pointed out, there are paid vendors that do have controls like these, think of Telerik, Syncfusion and Devexpress. I think Syncfusion has a community license that you can use for free as long as you adhere to certain criteria.

Comment: DevExpress says it's free in their website for .net maui datagrid. But I think it won't support desktop version. Could you plz confirm once.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, I'm not that familiar with DevExpress, but looks like it's only supported on iOS and Android for now.